# Can one combine multiple languages into one binary?

Tags: java, c, binary, jvm

For example there could be a bit of java byte code mixed together with some C. Jvm will execute java byte code and turns execution over to OS if a C part is hit. Is this technically possible or in practice?

Comment: Not exactly. It is possible to call native code with JNI (or JNA), but it's C++ (so you'd have to link to it through C++).

Comment: There is [GCC Bridge](http://www.renjin.org/blog/2016-01-31-introducing-gcc-bridge.html), a C compiler for the JVM.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch JNI/JNA also work for C. (IIRC, JNA works _only_ for C).

Comment: Java code isn't usually stored in "a binary", but in a JAR file (which is binary as in not a source file, but is not directly executable).

Comment: @JornVernee It isn't a C compiler. It is a GCC backend that plugs into any of the GCC family of compilers.

Comment: The JNA library has both Java byte code and shared libraries written in C in the one JAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can write C code which creates JVM, executing (execve) provided bytecode and either run them in separate threads with some IPC between or using JNA/JNI to exchange the data, or make operations and wait for completion.

I met some projects using this approach (for example part of Android system, Cloudera Impala and some others), but the code there is overcomplicated and hardly traceable.  For sure it's took too much effort to make it work properly. Sometimes it's better either run 2 processes using different technologies with good IPC with data serialization (thrift, protobuf) or use only one of them.

If you still need to run both, I'd prefer to build a system in Java calling native functions with JNI rather than opposite.